# Python Sending Message on Facebook

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a message in Messenger using Python

```
import fbchat 
from getpass import getpass 
username ="09471260496" 
client = fbchat.Client(username, getpass()) 
no_of_friends = int(raw_input("Number of friends: ")) 
for i in xrange(no_of_friends): 
    name = str(raw_input("Name: ")) 
    friends = client.getUsers(name)  # return a list of names 
    friend = friends[0] 
    msg = str(raw_input("Message: ")) 
    sent = client.send(friend.uid, msg) 
    if sent: 
        print("Message sent successfully!")
```

I already install `pip3 install fbchat` and when i try to click tools>Build Nothing is showing. What do you think that is happening? I'm using sublime as my text editor by the way

Comment: Which platform are you working on(Windows/Linux)?

Comment: Windows Platform

Comment: Do you get any output in the bottom left, beside the line and column number? e.g. `No Build System`? Can you run your program directly with python? I recommend that first before configuring sublime

Comment: Yeah, it is asking for password. When I enter password it returns ```fbchat._exception```

Answer (score 0):

On PyCharm, File->Settings-> (ALT+Insert) or `+` sign on right-upper corner -> type `fbchat` then `install package`. It worked on my case. I am using PyCharm on Windows 10.